# MySQL database() vs database name

Tags: mysql, sql

I constructed a query where i use:

```
where table_schema=database()
```

but if i replace `database()` with the `database-name` i get an empty resultset.

Why is that?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

The whole query:

```
SELECT table_name from information_schema.tables where
table_schema=database()
```

the databasename is

```
training
```

Comment: Can you post the entire query and the name of the database?

Comment: do you have quotes around `database-name`?

Comment: If you try "select database();" will give you database name. 
But "select database-name" give you nothing....

Comment: there is no - in the database name. I tried to use quotes without success.
I do not "Select database-name". Select database() returns the databases i got.

Comment: SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'training';  this worked for me..

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the problem.

```sql
mysql> CREATE DATABASE `training`;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE `training`;
Database changed

mysql> CREATE TABLE `test_table`(`c0` INTEGER);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `table_name`
    -> FROM
    ->   `information_schema`.`TABLES`
    -> WHERE
    ->   `table_schema` = DATABASE();
+------------+
| table_name |
+------------+
| test_table |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `table_name`
    -> FROM
    ->   `information_schema`.`TABLES`
    -> WHERE
    ->   `table_schema` = 'training';
+------------+
| table_name |
+------------+
| test_table |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```